# Accidentally favourited a tweet

Tags: twitter

I'm a Twitter private user. I accidentally favourited a guy’s tweet. I immediately un-favourited and then I blocked the guy.

I know he will still receive the email. My question is: the email will say that my username favourited one of his tweets? Is he going to able to check and see my name and profile when getting the notification? What’s going to happen?

Answer (score 2):

> Is he going to able to check and see my name and profile when getting the notification?

Yes, but since you've blocked the person, he/she can see the profile & username but won't be able to see any tweets if they're logged in. If they're logged out then the tweets will be visible.

Comment: Unless you protected your account. In this case your tweets are not shown even if he/she is logged out.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, he would still be able to see your name and profile when logged in.  If you want to guarantee that he can't see your tweets, set your account to protected mode.